# Blend in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate in Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. When first installation window popped up I could see, "Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Blend". I chose all options and installed successfully.
But I could not find Blend anywhere in Visual Studio when I opened it to create a new WPF project. What am I missing? I'm using Windows 7 OS. Thanks.

Comment: Blend is a different application. Look for it under programs.

Comment: What a dumb I was!!! Much appreciation SchautDollar !!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an installation issue and overlooking obvious things

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for Blend in your start menu?

I have also installed VS 2012 Ult and my Blend works fine. In fact, I used it a few times to design Windows Store Apps